# Is it possible to do sendto() recvfrom() simultaneously?

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I'm making very simple TCP emulating network application using UDP socket.

But, I want to use and call `sendto()`, `recvfrom()` functions simultaneously to implement pipelining which uses protocol called "Selective Repeat".  I mean not ordering like send, wait, receive, send, wait, receive, ..., I mean acting like send, send, send, receive, send, send, receive,receive, like this, without any ordering of calling `sendto()`, `recvfrom()`, that is random calling of these functions.

But basically, if I can't use these functions simultaneously, `sendto()`, `recvfrom()` act like stop and wait protocol.

But, in pipelining implementation, `sendto()`, `recvfrom()` functions act simultaneously.

Should I use `pthread` or other solutions?? or multiplexing?

Answer (score 4):

To do just about *anything* simultaneously, you need to have multiple threads.

One thread would be calling `sendto` as needed, and the other would be in a loop calling `recvfrom`.

Comment: Not really. Non-blocking sockets plus (e)poll would also be a way.

Comment: one thread for calling sendto in the infinite loop, and other thread for calling recvfrom in the infinite loop?

Comment: @Olaf You mean one thread can be in two places at the same time? Come now.

Comment: @EJP: No, I mean using non-blocking or async IO (not sure if the latter is possible, but the first is). Which way depends on the actual application and various other circumstances. If you only have 1 CPU, there also will never be 2 threads active at the **same** time.

Comment: @A.Cho Essentially, yes.  On your receiving thread, you'll want to use `select` with a timeout so you can periodically check for an exit condition.

Comment: .and even if you have a dual core cpu but an half duplex bus (e.g. 1gb ethernet)  you are really sending and receiving data at the same time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Threads should used if you want to implement by yourself.
But go through select function in section 7.2 [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4.pdf) pdf if you want to use an inbuilt function. It is a powerful tool and most used.

What it basically does is it keeps track of connections that are ready to communicate.